# Any queue behind Step Function States

Tags: aws-step-functions

Is there any queue or some way of storage that works behind the scene in Step Function for each state? Eg. Say, Step function State machine gets triggered by lambda. Each state in State Machine has a activity poller associated with it. Now say, from 10 requests came to first state in Step function and poller associated with that state just executes 1 request and 9 of them are still pending.

So, my question where are these 9 requests gets stored in the meantime? Is my understanding correct of how it works? If they are stored somewhere, for how much time will they be stored?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood it correctly then you mean if a State Machine (SM) is executed 10 times so first activity task is invoked in each SM. Each SM execution's activity task will wait for the response from the Worker. The activity task Worker polling using GetActivityTask API action will receive 10 responses `input`& `taskToken` from each SM separately. Worker must include the `taskToken` in subsequent calls to `SendTaskHeartbeat`, `SendTaskSuccess` or `SendTaskFailure` in order to report the progress or completion of the task for each SM. Activity state should include `TimeoutSeconds` as suggested in the [best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sfn-stuck-execution.html).